# How can I dynamically set the select option?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have these JSON object:

> ```
> [
>   {
>     id: "IYQss7JM8LS4lXHV6twn",
>     address: "US",
>     orderStatus: "On the way",
>   },
> ];
> ```

I wanted to have a select option for the order status. Let's say the current order status is at "On the way", the previous order status "confirmed" should be disabled. How can I implement this dynamically?

[image]

So far, these are my codes:

```
const status = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const handleChange = (e) => setValue(e.target.value);

  return (
    <div>
          <FormControl>
            <InputLabel htmlFor="order-status">Order Status</InputLabel>
            <Select onChange={handleChange}>
              <MenuItem value={10}>Confirmed</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={20}>On the way</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={30}>Delivered</MenuItem>
            </Select>
          </FormControl>

          {/* <p>{value}</p> */}

    </div>
  );
};

export default status;
```

Comment: can you share a sandbox link?

Comment: So if your status is `Delivered` than options `Confirmed` and `On the way` should be disabled?

Comment: @PriyankKachhela yes

Answer (score 1):

First you need to initialize `value` state with appropriate value. If your api returns `orderStatus` as `On the way` then need to initialize with value `20`

After that in `MenuItem` you can disable other option with simple check like below:-

```
<MenuItem value={10} disabled={value > 10}>Confirmed</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value={20} disabled={value > 20}>On the way</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value={30} disabled={value > 30}>Delivered</MenuItem>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Just a question though, since my api returns the value "On the way", how can I initialize it with the value of 20?

Comment: I think you can easily do that with switch case and useEffect.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping the current value as a state, maintain the previous value as well. There are many ways to achieve that.

Option 1

```
const [[current, prev], setValues] = useState(["", null]);
const handleChange = e => setValues([e.target.value, current]);
```

Option 2

```
const [{ current, prev }, setValue] = useState({current: "", prev: null});
const handleChange = e => setValue({
  current: e.target.value, 
  prev: current
});
```

Then in the `MenuItem`

```
// value is one of [10, 20, 30] in your example
<MenuItem disabled={value === prev}/>
```